# How switch to 3 or more different views from one table with dynamic cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, view, storyboard

I have view with table, table are filled dynamic data. I need to switch to different view depending on the particular row.
I need to check if the user clicks on a row with the word "BMW" then you need to open the "machine" view, and if the row with the word "suzuki" then open the motorcycle view.
And i use for this storyboard.

Comment: With story board i don't now how do this. i tried with xib file.     ImageViewController *obj =[[ImageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ImageViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES]; but it did not work

Comment: There are many question on SO about this topic. Use `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just connect all the controllers from segue to this controller. Do note that don't connect segue to any button's otlet instead connect it with whole viewcontroller. Then follow below steps :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSString * name = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"BMW"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MachineViewController" sender:self];

    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"suzuki"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MotorCycleViewController" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in `UITableView`

For Example :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSString * name = [namesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([name isEqualToString:@"BMW"])
    {
        //Open Machine View

        MachineInfoController * info = [[MachineInfoController alloc] init];

        // If you use `UINavigationController` use this line
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];

        // If you are not using `UINavigationController` use this line
        [self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];

        info = nil;
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"suzuki"])
    {
        //Open Motorcycle View

        MotorCycleInfoController * info = [[MotorCycleInfoController alloc] init];

        // If you use `UINavigationController` use this line
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:info animated:YES];

        // If you are not using `UINavigationController` use this line
        [self presentViewController:info animated:YES completion:nil];

        info = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: but what to write in this line //Open Machine View

Comment: I use your code, and i have exception, '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ImageView" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: Now i have black screen if i click on the row